# Want to use Calendar which will have some specific features in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, calendar

I am working on ReactJS project. I want to use Calendar which will highlight Indonesian holidays, and also I want to highlight some specific dates and disable other dates.

I am searching over the google and tried many solutions but didn't get any solution as I required.

I would love to appreciate any help from you guys.

Thanks in advance.